# Comparing columns in with() function eloquent fails

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a model Ledger in eloquent that has relation to currency table and the currency table has relation to exchange rates. When i try to get the exchange rate that has a date lower than that from the Ledger model the query fails. Here is my code.

```
Ledger::with('company')->with('order')->with(array('currency'=>function($query){
                $query->with(array('exchangeRates'=>function($query1){
                        $query1->whereRaw('exchange_date < ledgers.date');
                        $query1->orderBy('exchange_date','desc');
                        $query1->first();
                    }));

            }))->where('order_id','=',Input::get('order'))->get();
```

And here is my models
Ledger model

```
class Ledger extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = array(
    'company_code','order_id','account','sub_account',
    'date','document_number','document_desc','document_date',
    'booking_type','amount','currency_code','amount_currency'
);

public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Company','company_code','company_code');
}

public function order(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Order','order_id','id');
}
public function account(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Account','sub_account','id');
}
public function currency(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Currency','currency_code','id');
}
```

}

Currency model

```
class Currency extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = array('currency_shrt_name','currency_name',
    'currency_country','currency_unit');
public function exchangeRates(){
    return $this->hasMany('ExchangeRate','currency_code','id');
}
```

}
Exchange rate model

```
class ExchangeRate extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = array('exchange_date','currency_code','currency_value');
public function currency(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Currency','currency_code','id');
}
```

}

Comment: It fails, because `with` runs another query, not joins anything. So there can't be `ledgers.whatever` there. You have more issues in that code, but first tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to take the exchange rate for the resource based on the date of the resource. I will go with different approach because as you said with() function creates runs another query. My goal was to get results with single expression but that is not possible.

Comment: This is possible, just use joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fluent may be better suited for this query if you need to join and compare, as loading your relationships in Eloquent runs a separate select with no joins.

This query assumes your field names are named with standard naming conventions.

```
DB::table('ledgers')
->join('companies', 'ledgers.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
->join('orders', 'ledgers.id', '=', 'orders.ledger_id')
->join('currencies', 'ledgers.id', '=', 'currencies.ledger_id')
->join('exchange_rates', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('currency.id', '=', 'exchange_rates.currency_id');
    })
->where('exchange_rates.exchange_date', '<', 'ledgers.date')
->where('orders.id','=', Input::get('order'))
->order_by('exchange_rates.exchange_date', 'desc')
->select('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
->get();
```